# appcompat-v7:21.0.0': No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'

Tags: android, gradle, xamarin.android, android-support-library, android-5.0-lollipop

When attempting to use the latest appcompat-v7 support library in my project, I get the following error:

```
/Users/greg/dev/mobile/android_project/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.0/res/values-v11/values.xml
Error:(36, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(36, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(36, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(36, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm getting this issue in eclipse. I had over a 100 errors because my SDK Build tools did not update to rev 21. Got different errors now though so... go to look into those.

Comment: Today I uninstalled and reinstalled Extras/Android Support Library (version 21.0.2) and note that its project.properties *still* incorrectly point to target=android-19 which is the root of the problem. Should be 21, but it's a generated - not hand-editable -  file. See accepted answer for workaround.

Comment: @RED_, 
 
Cannot resolve symbol 'android:Theme.Material.Light' in <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light"></style> in valules-v21 in android studio

Comment: @PankajNimgade I don't understand... do you need help?

Comment: @RED_, yes i do need help desperately, on my computer I can't seem to detect anything for Material Theme or anything which starts with android in values-v21\styles, kindly help me

Comment: @PankajNimgade You should search SO or open a new question.

Answer (score 598, accepted):

While the answer of [loeschg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26431677/982852) is absolutely correct I just wanna elaborate on it and give a **solution for all IDE's** (Eclipse, IntellJ and Android Studio) even if the errors differentiate slightly.

---

### Prerequirements

Make sure that you've downloaded the latest `extras` as well as the `Android 5.0 SDK` via the SDK-Manager.

[image: Picture of the SDK Manager]

---

### Android Studio

Open the `build.gradle` or `build.gradle.kts` file of your app-module and change your `compileSdkVersion` to 21. It's basically not necessary to change the `targetSdkVersion` SDK-Version to 21 but it's recommended since you should always [target the latest android Build-Version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14939070/982852).
In the end you gradle-file will look like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion(21)
    // ...

    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        targetSdkVersion(21)
    }
}
```

Be sure to sync your project afterwards.

[image: Android Studio Gradle Sync reminder]

---

### Eclipse

When using the `v7-appcompat` in Eclipse you have to use it as a library project. It isn't enough to just copy the *.jar to your `/libs` folder. Please read [this (click)](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) step-by-step tutorial on *developer.android.com* in order to know how to import the project properly.

As soon as the project is imported, you'll realize that some folders in the `/res`folder are red-underlined because of errors such as the following:

[image: Errors in Eclipse]

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.*'
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
```

#### Solution

The only thing you have to do is to open the `project.properties` file of the `android-support-v7-appcompat` and change the target from `target=android-19` to `target=android-21`.
Afterwards just do a `Project --> Clean...` so that the changes take effect.

---

### IntelliJ IDEA (not using Gradle)

Similiar to Eclipse it's not enough to use only the `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar`; you have to import the `appcompat` as a module. Read more about it on this [StackO-Post (click)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025942/how-do-i-add-a-library-android-support-v7-appcompat-in-intellij-idea).
(***Note:*** *If you're only using the `.jar` you'll get `NoClassDefFoundErrors` on Runtime*)

When you're trying to build the project you'll face issues in the `res/values-v**` folders. Your message window will say something like the following:

```
Error:android-apt-compiler: [appcompat]  resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(75, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] C:\[Your Path]\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
// and so on
```

#### Solution

Right click on `appcompat` module --> Open Module Settings (F4) --> *[Dependency Tab]* Select Android API 21 Platform from the dropdown --> Apply

[image: Select API 21 Platform]

Then just rebuild the project (Build --> Rebuild Project) and you're good to go.

Comment: i am also facing same prob in eclipse after change the target from target=android-19 to target=android-21 also getting error on value folder dude

Comment: That's surprising. Did you clean & rebuild the project? Maybe you should import the project once again.

Comment: When I change AppCompat to 5.0 in eclipse, it no longer builds and the .bin folder is empty.

Comment: I was using Eclipse ADT and changing the target from Android 19 to 21 did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, really i was struggling from past 2 days, but ur trick change Android-19 to 21 worked.. Thanks Man

Comment: Using Eclipse, I had to update the project target to 21 on all projects that were using the appcompat library, not only on the appcompat project itself.

Comment: Great answer! I was missing the "Google repository" in the SDK manager, which caused an `error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.`

Comment: @reVerse, iam still getting 
 
Cannot resolve symbol 'android:Theme.Material.Light' in <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light"></style> in valules-v21 in android studio

Comment: That is great answer. just a note, I had to modify the target to be android-# with the latest android api level that I installed on my sdk

Comment: I am currently wrestling with the previous issues mentioned in eclipse / android.  It really is a load of unreliable impenetrable bollocks.

Comment: Thanks! This was so helpful. I had to change mine to 23 though.

Answer (score 124):

This is likely because you haven't set your `compileSdkVersion` to 21 in your build.gradle file. You also probably want to change your `targetSdkVersion` to 21.

```
android {
    //...
    compileSdkVersion 21

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
    //...
}
```

This requires you to have downloaded the latest SDK updates to begin with.

[image: Android Studio SDK Manager]

Once you've downloaded **all the updates** (don't forget to also update the Android Support Library/Repository, too!) and updated your compileSdkVersion, re-sync your Gradle project.

**Edit: For Eclipse or general IntelliJ users**

See reVerse's answer. He has a very thorough walk through!

Comment: This is the correct answer.
Upgrading to 21 requires this, the new appcompat dependencies, and you need to download rev 12 of play services.

Comment: And be sure to run JDK 7

Comment: While still correct, see @reVerse's solution. It's more thorough :)

Comment: didn't use neither one of the IDEs nor Gradle... is it similar when I use Ant and Notepad?

Answer (score 22):

`Follow below steps:

its working for me.To resolve this issue,

1.Right Click on appcompat_v7 library and select Properties

2.Now, Click on Android Option,
Set Project Build Path as Android 5.0 (API level 21)
Apply Changes.

3.Now go to project.properties file under appcompat_v7 library,

4.Set the project target as : target=android-21

5.Now Clean + Build appcompat_v7 library and your projects`

Comment: I used your way and set android-21 target in project and library and then clean both and done..thanks.

Comment: where can I find the appcompat_v7 library?

Comment: you can find appcompat_v7 lib in : adt-bundle-windows-x86_64
 -->sdk
-->\extras\
-->android\
-->support
-->v7

Comment: This answer in combination with loeschg's answer above resolved this issue in Eclipse.

Answer (score 12):

In case you don't want to use API 21 as the target API, and thus you don' t want to use the Material Theme, you have to use an older revision belonging to API 19 >

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+"
```

This also helps solving your problem, it only depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I agree with you. After all, not everyone plans to target sdk at 21.

Answer (score 9):

I have encountered this issue with play-services:5.0.89. Upgrading to 6.1.11 solved problem.

Answer (score 8):

In Android Studio I was trying to set the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to `19`.

My solution was to replace at the bottom of `build.gradle`, *from* this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

To the older version of the appcompat library:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

Comment: i was using a latest version from appcompact but now i want to doengrade to earlier version but i'm getting this error in exploded-arr folder

Answer (score 3):

I had added another project to my workspace and was trying to reference an activity from it in the manifest file, and I was getting this error. The problem is I was referencing the library incorrectly. This is how I fixed the problem:

- Right click on project
- Select Properties
- Click on Android on left menu
- Click on Add
- Please select a Library Project

The jar went into **Android Dependencies** folder and this error was fixed.

Comment: I executed your sequence. Then had a «Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies» in the Android console because jars in libs/ and jars in dependent appcompat and google play services library projects were not matching (were having mismatching SHA-1 and jar file length). Struggling further, I consider this a success.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you clean your project in android studio (or eclipse),

It should solve your issues

Comment: Cleaning your project in this case does not work, especially if you've just downloaded a new Android SDK, appcompat library, etc., as errors won't magically clean themselves without finding the missing links to other Android libraries and/or resources. **ReVerse**'s answer is correct and most thorough for those who do not know how to resolve issues with the latest Android API level 21 download by themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to latest gradle plugin solve my problem :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.+'
```

Comment: 0.14.0 was actually released not too long ago

Comment: yep, I was still using 0.12... maybe it can help someone else upgrading to 0.13 or 0.14

Answer (score 2):

After creating a second project in the workspace in eclipse, I had this problem. I believe it is because I created it with a different SDK version and this ovewrote the android-support-v7-appcompat library.

I tried to clean everything up but to no avail. Ultimately, the suggestion above to edit project.properties and change target=android-21 and set my project to Android 5.0, fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

What I recomend is: (This works to me after many days with errors)

-Make sure that you have downloaded:

```
- the Lastest SDK Platform from the latest Android version
- Android Suppor Librarie and Repository from EXTRAS
```

-Redowload the ADT

-Make a security copy of your project.

-You must have the ADT, the workspace and the project that we will import in the same disk (e.g. C:/)

1. Now delete the app compat and your project.
2. In eclipse: File > Import > Android existing project > Next > Browse (The folder where you have your ADT)/sdk/extras/android/v7/appcompat > Import > Finish
3. Now in the eclipse Package Explorer: android-support-v7-appcompat/libs/ Make on the two JARS: Right click > Build Path > Add to Build Path
4. Right click on libs/ folder > Buil Path > Configure Build Path and check this two JARS > OK
5. On the upper eclipse bar > Project > Clean
6. Import your project > File > Import > Browse your project > Finish
7. Now, Right click on the projectfile and android-support-v7-appcompat > Properties > Android > And select the latest API that appears > OK
8. Right click on the projectfile > Properties > Android > Add > android-support-v7-appcompat
9. On the upper eclipse bar > Project > Clean

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error when I changed the Compile SDK version from API:21 to API:16. The problem was, **appcompat** version. If you need to use an older version of android API, so you have to change this appcompat version also. In my case (**for API:16**), I had to use **appcompat-v7:19.+**.

So I replace dependencies in **build.gradle** as follows,

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

And make sure you have older versions of appcompat versions on your SDK
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was up to date with everything and still got this error, not sure why but I think the image was corrupted in a strange way and after replacing the image I got rid of the error.
Might be worth to try with a different image :)

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had other libraries that my project referenced and those libraries had another version of appcompat referenced. This is what I did to resolve the issue:

(You should back up your project before doing this)

1) I deleted all the appcompat layout folders (ex: /res/layout-v11).

2) Solved the problems that arose from that, usually an error in menu.xml

3) Back to main project and add appcompat library, clean, and everything works!