# Lollipop AppCompat-v7 21 - Attribute "theme" has already been defined

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I wanted to upgrade my project to support Android Lollipop and API 21, so I changed AppCompat version at the dependencies to 21.0.0,
and my target SDK to 21.

But now, When I'm trying to sync project with gradle files, it gives me `102 errors` that weren't there before:

1 error of `"Attribute 'theme' has already defined"` - given by my `colors.XML` file,

and another 101 errors of `"no resources found that matches the given name..."` - most of them are Material ones - given by `"build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.0/res/values-v11/values.XML"`.

Already updated all SDK tools in Android SDK software,
Using Android Studio 0.8.9 Beta.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro

Comment: update your SDK per the question/answer linked above

Answer (score 123, accepted):

I had the first issue as well. It can be fixed by updating the Google Play Services dependency to 6.1.+.

In Gradle (which I hope you are using) this is:
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'

As for the second issue - as people have said in the comments, you should make sure ALL the components in your SDK installation are up to date.

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed the Google Play Services dependency and it worked!

Comment: I updated all the components and I'm not using GPlay services, but it still not working... Would you have another idea? EDIT: Changed all my other dependencies replacing version numbers by "+" and it works. Note this is just a temporary fix

Comment: @tilal6991 For me none of the above responses are working including comments. I've even tried to change my build tools but it had no effects. Heeeeelp !!!! :S

Comment: @SeïfaneIdouchach check that its not defined anywhere else in your `attrs.xml` or any third party dependency that defines `theme` in an attributes file.

Comment: I had very similar issues. Resolved them by updating my submodules to the latest versions of Google Play Services, AppCompat, and Support libraries as well.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem but upgrade to latest versions doesn't helped.

But error message `Attribute “theme” has already been defined` changed to `Attribute “layout” has already been defined`

In Google Play Services changes I've found this

```
  <declare-styleable name="WalletFragmentOptions">
         <!-- Theme to be used for the Wallet selector -->
-        <attr name="theme" format="enum">
+        <attr name="appTheme" format="enum">
```

And this is the key.

If you have in your attr.xml attributes **theme** or **layout** or maybe something else  -  rename it. It seems merger can't deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

Gradle in the Android studio suggests the latest version of `com.google.android.gms:play-services`.
After updating that to the latest version, the problem got solved.

compile `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the library you are using has this attribute. I was using [Sliding up panel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) library and I got following error during build time. I had following items in my dependency libraries:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:+'
    // ...
}
```

I fixed my problem by removing sliding library :(

Comment: This issue in SlidingUpPanel has now been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

After adding a new activity in my project, it seems like Android Studio automatically updated my dependencies, after what that error started to appear.

I changed the following dependencies to the latest compatibility libraries:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```

to the ones I had in my gradle.build before Studio edited it without asking me:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
```

Then let Studio make a Sync, and your build should work.

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse-users:

- go with the [accepted answer from tilal6991](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26432590/1885518)
- but bear in mind, that you have to reimport the google play service project afterwards

Because if you followed the recommandation for installing gps, you only have a copy of it in your workspace, which won't get updated.