# Im getting few errors that make no sense, take a look

Tags: android, xml

So here hare the errors im getting:

### Below is the picture of the Error:

[image: the project file screen shot]

---

### And below is the picture of my Project Window:

[image: Project Window]

I have all the values and fields defines in the setup.xml. However eclipse is saying that it cannot find the values/fields. Why is that? If you look at the oncreate method im trying to launch setup.xml. If you look on the left hand side of the screen shot i clearly have setup.xml.

Comment: your resources are not being saved in R.java file in gen folder I guess, Open R.java and see if you have fields which you are trying to refer

Comment: There are build path errors, Go to `project right click > Properties > Java Build Path` and see what are the errors.

Comment: Did you try clean build?

Comment: Yeah i already tried clean build.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to styles_base.xml error - file of appcompat library. Easiest option is remove dependency on appcompat.  Right click your project > Properties > Android > Library > Remove the reference to the appcompat. Make sure your code is not using it anymore. For further knowledge check here: [AppCompat Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26677176/891092)