# Android appcompat v7 - imported with an error

Tags: android, eclipse, import, adt, eclipse-adt

I just created a new Android project in Eclipse. After that I managed to import the android-support-v7-appcompat lib. Unfortunately an errors are given:

```
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:178: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:182: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:113: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:115: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:110: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:107: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:121: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:126: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:138: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:143: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:129: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:132: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:146: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:150: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:154: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:158: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:164: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:168: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:172: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:174: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:97: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:101: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:62: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:42: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:50: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:52: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:54: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Dialog'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v11/themes_base.xml:338: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v14/themes_base.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v11/themes_base.xml:345: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v14/themes_base.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v11/themes_base.xml:352: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v14/themes_base.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v11/themes_base.xml:359: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v14/themes_base.xml:53: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:202: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:212: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:205: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:219: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:223: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:81: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:83: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:84: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:82: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:79: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:80: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:118: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:120: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:121: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:119: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:116: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:117: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:155: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:157: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:158: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:156: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:153: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:154: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:192: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:194: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2015-02-08 16:23:01 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
../res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:195: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
```

And that's not even the whole error log. The complete one is [here](http://pastebin.com/zLrJQsLq).
I have the latest sdk installed. Ther error is in res/values-v21/styles_base.xml Do you have any idea what causes this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: I did the following, Project, Properties, Android, choose android 5.0.1, Project, Properties, Choose Java Compiler 1.7 and in the manifest     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in styles\_base.xml file - android app - No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530415/error-in-styles-base-xml-file-android-app-no-resource-found-that-matches-the)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530415/error-in-styles-base-xml-file-android-app-no-resource-found-that-matches-the/27243716#27243716) fixed my problem. I don't know why it is not accepted but it worked out for me.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

To solve, download this appcompat v7 and import in to your workspace.

[android-support-v7-appcompat](https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-v7-appcompat)