# How to add "Android Design Support Library" to Eclipse with ADT-plugin?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, eclipse-adt, android-design-library

[The Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) announced in May 2015:

> The Design library is available now, so make sure to update the Android Support Repository in the SDK Manager.

I am using Eclipse (Version: Luna 4.4.2) with latest ADT-plugin and don't see anything "design" in the SDK manager:

[image: SDK manager]

When trying to use [android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) or [android.support.design.widget.NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) in my projects like [this one](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/q33/NavigationDrawerExample) -

[image: app screenshot]

I unfortunately get errors:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.NavigationView" on path ...

If I would be using Android Studio, I probably needed the line

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

but how to fix this in Eclipse? Can I download a JAR file for the design library?

I have searched `\sdk\extras\android\support\` path, but haven't found any.

Comment: did you tried using it as reference project? i was able to use google play services same way

Comment: Here the info to setup: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res: Time to switch to Android Studio

Comment: No, it is about appcompat ( which works for me already ) - and not about design library

Comment: you have to put Jar file of support library in lib Folder and you are Done.you can find jar file from this path in SDK folder  :: sdk\extras\android\support\design\libs

Comment: make sure you are using "Theme.AppCompat.[...]"  in your base theme

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Before use the design support library, you have to import **support-v7-appcompat library** from *android-sdks\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat*. Then, you have to:

- create an android library project in eclipse for **design support library**
- put the contents of directory *android-sdks\extras\android\support\design* in the **design support library project**
- Link **appcompat-v7 library** to **design support library project**
- Link **support library** project from your project.

> **Note:** If you can't find the *design* folder you might want to try this location instead:
>   `android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\design`

You can not use directly the jar android-support-design.jar because you need some resources too (this is the reason of aar format).

For more info just check [Error in styles_base.xml file - android app - No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530415/error-in-styles-base-xml-file-android-app-no-resource-found-that-matches-the)

Comment: Thanks (+1), but unfortunately I get numerous resource-related errors like `extras\android\support\design\res\values\styles.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button'.`

Comment: Hi! I have updated the answer. The design support library need the support-v7-appcompat library to be compiled.

Comment: I still can't find  the path `sdk\extras\android\support\design\libs`  . I don't have design folder in my support folder

Comment: @Jas, did you have installed, with SDK manager, package "Android Support Library"? Folder you mentioned was installed when you select that module.