# How to use ripple in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse-luna, rippledrawable

I am using **eclipse luna** as IDE.I try to search how to use ripple but all of the results need **gradle** since they are using android studio.So,do you know **how to use ripple in eclipse**?Thank in advance.

Comment: For button ,have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604134/how-to-achieve-ripple-animation-using-support-library-in-android/29277996#29277996

Comment: Actually it is `gradle` based. Switch to `Android-Studio`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to use android design library in eclipse then check out this

[How to add "Android Design Support Library" to Eclipse with ADT-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430633/how-to-add-android-design-support-library-to-eclipse-with-adt-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

`Gradle` is the build tool the guys at android want us to stick to, because it makes building apps a whole lot easier. I would recommend looking into Android studio and gradle. Google have discontinued the whole eclipse for android development. As far as getting ripple into android eclipse project without gradle goes, i wudnt know much. But u can integrate gradle into your eclipse. Head to [this](http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/) website, you will make some head way.