# No resource identifier found for attribute 'layoutManager' in package 'android.support.design'

Tags: android, android-support-library

I added 'android.support.design' library as a dependency in my project

but the following error was found.

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'layoutManager' in package
>   'android.support.design'

[image]

What I have done so far..

1. Update to latest support library version
2. Add appcompat as its dependency (of "design library")
3. Check "design library" as a Library Module

Please help.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Is it a navigation drawer that you want to make?

Comment: Floating Action Button, it required design support library. however, when I included and build it give me this error.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The design library depends on **appcompat-v7** library as pointed out in [xcesco`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31431076/3876053). But (at least in rev. 23.1) it depends on **[v7-recyclerview](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-recyclerview)** library as well.

So basically you have two options:

1. Link v7-recyclerview library into your design support library project (in the same way you link the appcompat-v7 library)
2. Or you can get rid of the dependency by deleting line `app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"` in the 
   `..design\res\layout\design_navigation_menu.xml` file. (If you are not using NavigationMenu from the design library, or hoping to fix this issue later)

*Thanks for making this clear in the docs Google!*

Comment: @Jongz Puangput This is the right answer. please accept it

Comment: Added the recyclerview library to my design project and it worked, great!

Comment: and please don't forget to check v7-recycleview module as library module as well

Answer (score 3):

To use android.support.design add this as gradle dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

And you are good to go....

Comment: it's an old project not port to gradle yet. thank for answer.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430633/how-to-add-android-design-support-library-to-eclipse-with-adt-plugin

Comment: I try what you mention in link above. but no hope

Comment: Did you successfully added the library to the project?