# Using TabLayout in Android Eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to use a `TabLayout` in an Android project using Eclipse and Andmore but haven't been able to find a jar containing the required `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` class.

Googling a bit, it seems I need the `com.android.support:design:22.2.0` library. However, the latest version I can find in my SDK installation (under `extras/android/support`) is v17.

Where can I find this library (without having to migrate to Android Studio)?

Comment: use android studio 2.0........

Comment: Download it from JCenter like Gradle would do? Or better, move to Android Studio?

Comment: I think it is in the folder extras/android/support/design in your SDK-installation. It will be up-to-date, if you SDK is up-to-date. Don't look at the v17-folder

Comment: try this answer... http://stackoverflow.com/a/31431076/3678308

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a few other answers I finally managed to import everything. Putting it all together, just copyiing the jar into `libs` will not be sufficient. Here's how it works in Andmore (ADT should be similar but some options apparently differ):

- Make sure your SDK is up to date. Specifically, you want the latest version of **Extras > Android Support Library** (should be version 22 or higher) and a matching version of **Tools > Android SDK Build-tools**.
- If you have a copy of `android-support-v4.jar` in the `libs` folder of your app's source tree, replace it with a recent copy from `<sdk>/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs`. (If you have other Android support JARs in that location, you may need to update those as well.)
- Copy `<sdk>/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat` and `<sdk>/extras/android/support/design` into your workspace folder. (Not really necessary, but using a local copy will prevent polluting your SDK setup with Eclipse-generated files.
- Select **File > New... > Android Project**.
- Select **Create project from existing source** and select your copy of the `appcompat` folder. Be sure to select at least API 22 as a build target (I needed to use API 23, YMMV), and don't forget to give it a meaningful name.
- When import has finished, open the properties of the new project, go to **Android** and check **Is Library**.
- Repeat the same two steps to import the design library. After import, in its project properties, go to **Android**, and in **Libraries** add a reference to the `appcompat` project.
- Open the properties of your app project, go to **Android**, and in **Libraries** add a reference to the `design` project.

I had to make some minor modifications to my source code as some resource identifiers are no longer constants as of API 14, requiring me to convert a `switch` statement to a series of `if`s. After that, I could finally build my app.

This should work for other Android libraries as well – their locations are documented in http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html.

**Edit:** <del>There may be an easier way:</del> Both ADT and Andmore also have **Android Tools > Add Support Library**, <del>which might make a few of the aforementioned steps easier</del>, which installs the most recent version of the support library. But you still have to add them to your project by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Update your sdk using sdk manager.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. Finding the libraries was the issue – as well as the rather lengthy process of installing them.

Answer (score -1):

Got it. Everything's there if you update your SDK to the latest version, things are just a bit hidden in the folder tree. You'll need three JARs:

- `extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v4.jar` (the file was already in my project but I upgraded it anyway – not sure if it was necessary)
- `extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar`
- `extras/android/support/design/libs/android-support-design.jar`

Copy these three to your project's `libs` dir, refresh your project in Eclipse (cleaning won't hurt as well) and you should be good.

Library locations are documented in http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

Comment: You should add them as Android Library projects. With this method, you do not include the resources which are needed.

Comment: This will be the way to go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430633/how-to-add-android-design-support-library-to-eclipse-with-adt-plugin/31431076#31431076

Comment: Thanks – which of the project types would I select to create the design library project? It says something about "Android Library" but I don't have that as a project type.

Comment: You should have this option? Do you have ADT installed?

Comment: No, I'm on Andmore. It's a fork of ADT but some things seem to be different.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I'm sorry. I do not know this plugin. But nevertheless, I think you would save a lot of time, when switching to Android Studio.

Comment: Apparently with Andmore you create an "Android Project" from existing source (make a copy to avoid polluting your SDK setup) and mark it as a library afterwards. The only remaining issue is an error message in `res/values/styles.xml`: `No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'backgroundTint'`

Comment: Fixed it – turns out the v7 appcompat library needs to be added in the same manner.