# The following classes could not be instantiated: - android.support.design.widget.*;

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to use some of the widgets like TabLayout, CoordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout from the design package. But I am getting the following errors:

The following classes could not be instantiated:

```
android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Error Log)

android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout (Open Class, Show Error Log)

android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Error Log)

android.support.design.widget.TabLayout (Open Class, Show Error Log)
```

See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.

I came across many solutions like to add those in dependencies, update SDKs, etc. for these types of errors,  but I think they seem to work only with Android Studio. I am using Eclipse Luna and my SDKs are up-to-date and I have imported and added the design package to my project. I don't know how to solve this with Eclipse. Any Suggestions???

Comment: Follow this link [Add design support library to eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430633/how-to-add-android-design-support-library-to-eclipse-with-adt-plugin)

Comment: You should migrate to android studio because android completely stop to provide support for eclipse.

Comment: @USKMobility Unfortunately I have to proceed in Eclipse, Because I have completed 90% of my Project and another problem is my low system configuration :(