# Cannot find google play services or android support library in SDK

Tags: android, sdk

I am not new to android development or android SDK, I have been using it for years. Today I decided to get the latest SDK from google, so I downloaded it, installed api 21 SDK platform, and other stuff, however, I cannot find the **Android support library** or **Google play services** in SDK manager or the SDK folder (google play services shows up in the SDK manager, but not in the SDK folder)

what is wrong with this?
[image]]

Also I tried installing the latest SDK again from scratch 4 times

Comment: Eclipse is also not adding the support library to the projects i create

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. I'm starting to think it's due to not specifying a project for the SDK manager before installing google play services.

Answer (score 1):

Check  Under Tools, select Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform-tools and update.
Once updated, restart your SDK Manager. Android Support Repository will now be available under Extras.

Comment: how can i update something which is already up to date and i downloaded it from scratch, also it is clearly visible in the screenshot attached. someone down vote this please

Answer (score 0):

Please check in the android SDK Manager there is a Google Play Services is selected or try to update it again
And make sure you put them in gradle

```
 android{
 }
 dependencies{
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
 }
```

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file

Comment: my question clearly has a comment "
 
Eclipse is also not adding the support library to the projects i create " tagged with `maven`. so i don't have android studio or build.gradle file

Comment: Eclipse Support with android has ended. It won't support Gradle. Maybe you should export your project to Android Studio

Comment: unfortunately, my question isn't about Eclipse not supporting gradle.

Comment: Actually there is a Gradle plugin for Eclipse, so might want to look at that before you continue to say Eclipse doesn't support it

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot looks ok.

Make sure you also install "Google Repository" and "Android Support Repository"

After you have downloaded them you'll need to restart Android studio and add the dependencies in your gradle file.

Comment: "Android support Repository" is the new name for  "Android support library" so you'll need that. I'm afraid I can't help you on the eclipse part as I haven't used it in ages.

Comment: Play services seems correctly downloaded. Google Repository includes local Maven repository for Google libraries, which provide a variety of features and services for your apps, such as Google sign-in, Google Maps, Games achievements and leaderboards.

Comment: If you don't use Google libraries you don't need the Google Repository.

Comment: It is normal that you don't see a lib project folder. I can't tell you how to add it in eclipse as I don't use eclipse myself

Comment: now how do i import the "Android Support Repository" and "Google Repository" in my project? i have them downloaded and i am using eclipse

Comment: If it's within your possibilities I would strongly recommend you to switch your project to Android Studio. If this isn't possible maybe these steps might help you out http://stackoverflow.com/a/31431076/1185811

Comment: You're welcome to [edit] your post with these additional comments.