# android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout could not be instantiated

Tags: java, android, android-textinputlayout

I want to integrate `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` In my android application. I have copied the jar file **android-support-design.jar** from the sdk to my applications lib folder. I have added below code in my xml file for the Email EditText,

```
 <!-- Email Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="Email" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

While add this code in my layout.xml file I am getting an error like,

```
Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
```

How can i fix this issue...

Comment: I'm not sure how the mentioned code produced `MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup` please show the code that uses a mocking library

Comment: Also, you should use Gradle dependencies rather than jar files. Less problems will arise

Comment: did you added the jar file to compile in gradle dependency

Comment: I am using Eclipse for development

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you uses AndroidStudio, you should not include android-support-design.jar.
Instead, write like below in your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    ...
}
```

**Edit**: If this doesn't work you are probably using a different version. In Windows, go to:

```
[android-sdk]\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\design
```

On Mac:

```
sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design
```

This directory holds a number of version folders. Use the latest version on your build.gradle.

Comment: I am using Eclipse for development

Comment: You should import support-v7-appcompat library.
see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31431076/5183999

Comment: Thanks Its worked for me... I have added the library project from android-sdks\extras\android\support\design

Answer (score 50):

replace

```
android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

with

```
com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
```

Answer (score 7):

add in the build.gradle following this line:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

and use in the xml file:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/inputLayoutMobile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                    android:hint="@string/phone_number"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android.support.design:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputLayoutAppServerUrl">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtTxtMobile"
                        style="@style/Style_TextView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_smartphone"
                        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical"
                        android:text="@={SettingViewModel.mMobileNo}"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_13sp" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Shouldn't we use androidx libraries?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, replace the TextInputLayout design pattern with below resolved for me:

> com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

Answer (score 1):

The dependency your using is part of the Android support library which is now deprecated and no longer supported by Google. Instead, use this:
`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'`
and replace `<version>` with the latest version from either [Google's Maven Repository](http://maven.google.com/) or [MVN Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material)

Perhaps you could read more from here [Getting Started](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md)

Answer (score 1):

For android androidX add this dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
```

Then try

Answer (score 0):

If implementation, compile and api doesn't work try using classpath with latest version of material library you can find latest version on [Google's Maven Repository](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.google.android.material:material)

```
dependencies {
    .....
    classpath 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-beta01'
    ....
}
```

Answer (score -6):

You are making mistake in giving id
give id to TextInputLayout

Comment: there is no relevance of setting id , TextInputLayout is a part of material design library so we need to add the relevant library to get its intellisense autofill in xml.