# I got error when click on file java or xml file in android - Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am new in android and I tried to open my project in Eclipse get some error and does not open code of file.

Below errors:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.getScrollbarsMode()I

[SDK Manager] The system cannot find the path specified.


[ddms] Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700). Make sure you do not have another instance of DDMS or of the eclipse plugin running. If it's being used by something else, choose a new port number in the preferences.

[android-support-v7-appcompat] D:\Android\eclipse1\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
```

Any one have a idea. I tried lots of time but not get any solutions.

Thanks

Comment: Switch to Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `project.properties` file in your appcompat library project should use whatever the highest version of the API that your particular appcompat project has been written for (in your case it looks like v21).

As this is a possible duplicate of a solved question,For further info, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530415/error-in-styles-base-xml-file-android-app-no-resource-found-that-matches-the) question.

Comment: HI, can solved "android-support-v7-appcompat" error using your solutions but still error SDK manager is there. Any solutions for it? Thanks