# How to use material design in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, material-design

I am developing an android app in eclipse.I need to use material design.I tried by creating folder values-v21 but app will be crash.Can anyone guide me how to use material design in eclipse?.The style i have added is

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">

</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: `but app will be crash` ? which error comes ?

Comment: add material design lib in your project

Comment: Error is unable to start the activity component info you need to use a Theme.Appcompat theme

Comment: First of all there are no reasons to use Eclipse any more today.
Then you have to use an AppCompat theme not a Material Theme.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new Android Project with Target SDK version 21
2. Add `Appcompat v7` library to your workspace and add this lib to build path of your project(sdk\extras\android\support\v7)
3. Then you set Project build target to version 21
4. There should be only 2 values folder in res folder.

   - **values/styles.xml should be as below:**

> ```
> <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
>         // Your style here
> </style>
> ```

- **values-v21/style.xml should be as below.**

> 

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme"
parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
       ....
      // Your style here
</style>
```

Comment: [different style](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html)

Comment: when i created the app values-v21 does not appear.I have created it manually.but it does not works for me.target version is 21 only.

Comment: @ramyabr Appcompat v7 lib to add your workspace

Comment: appcompat_v7 is already there in the work space.

Comment: [check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530415/error-in-styles-base-xml-file-android-app-no-resource-found-that-matches-the/27243716#27243716)

Answer (score 0):

For you.. This is [Perfect Tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Troubleshooting-Eclipse-Issues#getting-java-lang-illegalstateexception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme). Here step by step explained **Troubleshooting Eclipse Issues**

First, try simply running **Project => Clean...** from the top-menu on the project and then re-running the app. If it still doesn't work, it might be the issue explained in the next paragraph.

This happens when the Android project was generated with a minimum SDK of 10 or below. One fix is to simply generate new projects with a minimum SDK of 14 instead. However when generating with a lower minSDK, in order to maintain compatibility with older versions, you'll notice that the activity Java class (i.e src/.../MainActivity.java) extends from `AppCompatActivity` rather than the standard Activity class. When an activity extends from `AppCompatActivity`, this requires the app to use a **"backwards compatible theme"**.

Easiest fix is to change the theme for the application within the **`AndroidManifest.xml`** such that application:theme is set to `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` as shown below:

[image]

May This Will Helpful to You.

> Note: I just want to give you advise that you can easily Google this
>   thing. Keep Googling First.