# Android Studio "Error retrieving parent, No resource found that match the given name" on TargetSdkVersion update to 23

Tags: android, android-studio

While updating TargetSdkVersion to 23 on project build using older targetVersion on Android Studio, i got following error on build.

```
/path/to/project/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values/values.xml
Error:(1334) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Base.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/path/to/AndroidSdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

The build.gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapplicaitonid"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.0.7"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false;
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
}
```

Tried : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27243716/4221298

but still same issues.

Anyone faced similar and solved?

Comment: #Bishnu . Post your build.gradle

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya minSdkVersion was 9. I am updating them. Lets c

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya no luck till now

Comment: Okay . I will check .Be patients .

Answer (score 2):

Got It

### This theme is deprecated.

Read **[TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.SearchResult.Subtitle](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/styles.xml)**

> Error:(1144) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   '@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Base.SearchResult.Subtitle'.

```
<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.SearchResult.Subtitle"
           parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Base.SearchResult.Subtitle">
</style>
```

As Android evolves with each new version, some behaviors and even appearances might change. However, if the API level of the platform is higher than the version declared by your app's targetSdkVersion, the system may enable compatibility behaviors to ensure that your app continues to work the way you expect.

**You can't call due to deprecation** .

> TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Base.SearchResult.Subtitle
>   DEPRECATED From API 23 .