# Android: error importing support appcompat v7

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm beating my head in that all day long.

I've done the exact process written here in the [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

But yet I'm not getting to importing the support library with no errors:

[image]

My workspace is empty and holds only this library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [appcompat-v7:21.0.0': No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro)