# android eclipse appcompatv7 error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

Hi i have problem in creating a new project in eclipse. I have errors in both `android support library` and  in my project. I tried removing the library project and added again as said by many websites. But Still end up with errors. Please guide me in this[image]

**SDK Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [appcompat-v7:21.0.0': No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the support library has updated definitions for Android 5.0 (Lollypop). Since resource folders such as values-v21 and layout-v21 have been defined in the support library, both your application and appcompat projects do not know API 21 since your build target is set for an older version of Android.

To resolve this, you need to make sure that both your application and the appcompat projects have the build target set to `Android 5.0` since the support library has updated values for the new Material theme that has been backported. It is a good idea to always target the latest versions so that you don't run into these issues with future updates to the support library.

You can do this in Eclipse by:

1. Right-click the project folder and select *Properties*
2. Select *Android* on the side menu
3. Select *Android 5.0* as the Project Build Target

[image: Eclipse Project Settings for Android Project]

You may need to download the `Android 5.0 (API 21) SDK Platform` in the SDK manager if you cannot find the Android 5.0 target.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on appcompat project and change the build version to android-5.0.

You have appcompat library which is having values-v21.

So, change the build version of android from 4.4.2 to 5.0

Comment: should i download Android 5.0

Comment: Yes, if you're not having you should download.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the library via `Right click project -> Android Tools -> Add Support Library`

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps.

1. Delete the android-support-v7-appcompat project (from the workspace, leave it on the disk)
2. Delete the android-support-v7-appcompat project (from the workspace, leave it on the disk)
3. Go to your project and select Properties -> Android, and remove android-support-v7-appcompat from  your references.
4. Perform clean
5. Re-import android-support-v7-appcompat.
6. Re-add appcompat as a reference for your project again.
7. Perform another clean of the project