# Android support library appcompat v7: cannot find actionModeShareDrawable resource

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I reinstalled the v7 appcompat library from the SDK manager in Eclipse. However, the library itself is telling me errors exist in several different xml files.

This is one of the theme files:

```
<resources>

<style name="Base.V14.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V11.Theme.AppCompat" />
<style name="Base.V14.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V11.Theme.AppCompat.Light" />
<style name="Base.V14.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" parent="Base.V11.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" />
<style name="Base.V14.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" parent="Base.V11.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" />

<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V14.Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:actionModeCutDrawable">?actionModeCutDrawable</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCopyDrawable">?actionModeCopyDrawable</item>
    <item name="android:actionModePasteDrawable">?actionModePasteDrawable</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSelectAllDrawable">?actionModeSelectAllDrawable</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeShareDrawable">?actionModeShareDrawable</item>
</style>

<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V14.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionModeCutDrawable">?actionModeCutDrawable</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCopyDrawable">?actionModeCopyDrawable</item>
    <item name="android:actionModePasteDrawable">?actionModePasteDrawable</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSelectAllDrawable">?actionModeSelectAllDrawable</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeShareDrawable">?actionModeShareDrawable</item>
</style>

<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" parent="Base.V14.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:actionModeCutDrawable">?actionModeCutDrawable</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCopyDrawable">?actionModeCopyDrawable</item>
    <item name="android:actionModePasteDrawable">?actionModePasteDrawable</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSelectAllDrawable">?actionModeSelectAllDrawable</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeShareDrawable">?actionModeShareDrawable</item>
</style>

<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" parent="Base.V14.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:actionModeCutDrawable">?actionModeCutDrawable</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCopyDrawable">?actionModeCopyDrawable</item>
    <item name="android:actionModePasteDrawable">?actionModePasteDrawable</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSelectAllDrawable">?actionModeSelectAllDrawable</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeShareDrawable">?actionModeShareDrawable</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

And the error:

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Eclipse section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26449172) might help you to solve the problem.

You have to do is to open the `project.properties file` of the `android-support-v7-appcompat` and change the target from `target=android-19` to `target=android-21`. The do a Clean for your project, restart your eclipse to take effect.

Comment: I think you should not manually edit project.properties, but rather build.gradle file.

Comment: thanks a lot.. very clear and perfect explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Right mouse click on v7 appcompat library project -> Properties -> Android -> make sure Android 5.0  is selected as Project Build Target.

Comment: this is the easier answer

Answer (score 0):

Its about targeting the correct version of android version.

goto

> Window>Android Sdk Manager>

See whether you are having the required version **SDK Build Tools** which can be found at top section of android sdk manager.

If you updated recently and deleted old Sdk Build tools that can be an issue too.

Please re-install the required tools.

Always remember don't delete the old Sdk Tools after updating to new ones.

Hope this Helps you.