# Xamarin Support Library v7 AppCompat 21.0.0-beta1

Tags: xamarin, android-appcompat

I am trying to use the latest Xamarin Support Library v7 AppCompat 21.0.0-beta1  in my project. I am getting the following error.

Xamarin/Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/21.0.0-appcompat-v7/embedded/./res/values-v11/values.xml:43: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.

It is pretty much identical to the issue on the following thread but it is related to xamarin envrionment.

[appcompat-v7:21.0.0': No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro)

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say you are "trying to use" what do you mean exactly, which class?

Answer (score 0):

You should override and set your target level to v21. You need to run the Xamarin Alpha channel to be able to do this.