# Appcompat v7 and ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I'm following [this](http://hmkcode.com/add-actionbar-to-android-2-3-x/) tutorial to make and app with action bar for 2.3.x devices. But i cannot import appcompat-v7 to my projecto... It gives me lots of errors like these:

```
[2014-11-06 14:19:23 - AcordeNoPonto] C:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:194: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-11-06 14:19:23 - AcordeNoPonto] C:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:195: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-11-06 14:19:23 - AcordeNoPonto] C:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:193: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-11-06 14:19:23 - AcordeNoPonto] C:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:190: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-11-06 14:19:23 - AcordeNoPonto] C:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:191: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-11-06 14:19:23 - AcordeNoPonto] C:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-large-v14\themes_base.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.
[2014-11-06 14:19:23 - AcordeNoPonto] C:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-large-v14\themes_base.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.
```

So i cannot import my app theme and my action bar is not shown...

Comment: Maybe [this will help (click)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro/26449172#26449172)

Comment: already did that... obviously did... now my project dont run anymore...

Answer (score 1):

In project.properties for Your project **android-support-v7-appcompat** Make sure target value as follow.
Project target.

```
target=android-21
android.library=true
```

once you done Clean your Project. I hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

In `project.properties` of both your project and `android-support-v7-appcompat` (under `res`), comment out the target api if not `target=android-21` and place the new target code there.

If this doesn't work, or you can't use 21+ api, make sure in your app's `project.properties` that `android.library=false`.

Next check your project's `Referenced Libraries` does not contain v4 in the buildpath. I believe I'm saying this correctly, that `v7-appcompat` required it (the previous version), but that it is included within the `android-support-v7-appcompat` file and thus the duplicate entries cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem too. I found many solutions that you must update to Android 5.0 API leveL 21..you can see one of the solutions for updating all IDE. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro/26449172#26449172)

..

(Note : Following method is my second way solution for me.)

If you don't want to update, you can try existing API level..I found solution in my way is that when you create the new android application project, choose as follow

`minSdkVersion= API 14 ,
targetSdkVersion=API 17 , 
compiled with=API 17`

Hope, this will help!