# error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge.Base'

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

Since i have changed my SDK ANDROID VERSION (API 21). I cant compile my program because i have this error in the resources the library "APPCOMPAT_V7".
Can anybody help me? Please.
thnks

Comment: [Did you edit the project.properties? (click)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro/26449172#26449172)