# Android 5.0 RuntimeException with AppCompat Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I just created Android project using [(hamburger) drawer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/32877/what-is-this-side-menu-called-that-can-be-found-in-many-multi-touch-apps-and-wh) with midSDKlevel set to android-8.

I first ran into [appcompat-v7:21.0.0': No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro) issue

, then running in Android 5.0 emulator I got RuntimeException

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

`\app\src\main\res\values-v21\styles.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    </style>
</resources>
```

Android manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**What exact string should be for Material Design with AppCompat ?**

Comment: Check the theme in your Android manifest ?

Comment: it has `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem between activity and style.You are using ActionBarActivity but you have Theme.Material.Light ,you should try `"Theme.AppCompat"` in your style

Comment: which style? write more info pls

Comment: i am using "Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" for toolbar you can use this.