# the error in eclipse about that no resource found while making new project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

As soon as I create a Android project in Eclipse Indigo I instantly get a resource error on the line, `setContentView(R.layout.main);` To make it worse, projects that were working now are having their `'gen'` folder emptied upon being built.
Unfortunately using google gives me a million references to projects that need to have files renamed or rebuilt, so I thought I'd ask here.

Errors

```
Description Resource Path Location Type error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'. themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v11 line 352 Android AAPT Problem error
```

The link provided by you didn't help me?
please help me?

```
appcompat-v7:21.0.0': No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'
```

Comment: see these http://stackoverflow.com/q/26431676/3879470   https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should fix the imports import the support library

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

the issue is you development environment is not able to resolve issue related to resource not able to compile as it is not able to find appropriate reference to external resources which your project is using