# Eclipse always uses android 5 build tools

Tags: android

I am trying to develop a android project with android Kitkat specification.

I have download latest version from SDK site and **updated 5 and 4.4.2** version.(like Shown in screenshot)

[image]

During initial project creation wizard, **selected "4.4 Kitkat" compiler**, (Like shown in screenshot)

[image]

After project created, i could see the errors in my problem window

"Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'."

[image]

**"appcompat_v7" project uses andriod L libraries.**

If I change the build version to android L (i.e. API 20) then error are corrected and i am getting library file.

Eclipse forcing me to use lollipop version API.

I have manually updated sdk version like below;

**sdk.buildtools=19**

Still same error throwing like shown above. I have done multiple clean and build the project. Nothing helps me.

Comment: Changed the target in eclipse, did clean and build multiple times. The values present in XML files are not changing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [appcompat-v7:21.0.0': No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro)