# Android appcompat_v7 error

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, android-appcompat

I get the following errors when I try to develop for API level 19, 21 works fine.

```
workspace/appcompat_v7/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
workspace/appcompat_v7/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
```

My API level in appcompat properties is set to 19.

Any suggestions?

edit: Given the answers I have seen it seems impossible to develop for API level 19. This surely cannot be the case?

Comment: material is not in 19. to have material in api 19 you need appcompat

Answer (score 0):

You may find your answer at this thread:

[**appcompat-v7:21.0.0': No resource found that matches the given name: **](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro)

You will find answer for both Android Studio and Eclipse.

Comment: So this means that I cannot have projects to target version 19? I must always target version 21?

Comment: That doesn't mean it. in the first comment it describes the way to solve this problem. what ide you ar  using ?

Comment: I am using Eclipse but the solution in the link says change both appcompat and the app your working on to API21 doesnt it, unless I am misunderstanding?

Comment: did you mention the target api during the creation of project or did you changed the target api after creating the project for greater api ?

Comment: I have deleted both the appcompat and project then created the project as minsdk 8, Target 19 and Compile with 19. Then I get many errors like the ones mentioned in my post

Comment: now just import the appcompat project from sdk directory to eclipse

Comment: don't forget to check the field that says copy project in working directory.

Comment: is there a specific appcompat for API19? When I create a project the appcompat is automatically added, does it just add the most recent? If so where do I find the API 19 appcompat?

Comment: there is no other appcompat. anyway can you please check your workspace if there is the appcompat project ?

Comment: The workspace does include an appcompat project, this has errors until I change the Target SDK to 21 and once doing so my application project gets errors as above.

Comment: now go to the project.propeties file of your appcompat project. make the target sdk/api to 21. that should work.

Comment: don't forget to save project and restart the ide.

Comment: Yeah I have done this and it gets rid of the errors in my appcompat but the errors in my application project persist and are the same as above, unless I make that also target api 21

Comment: did you tried it reverse ? changing the target api to 19 in appcompat ?

Comment: one more thing please be sure that sdk is updated and the extra section of the sdk manager is also updated.