# Error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist [ANDROID STUDIO]

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I'm trying to compile a project using Android Studio and this error show up. I've already imported the `appcompat` in the `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.1.0'
}
```

and in several files I've imported this:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

Comment: What's your `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="??"`

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

Comment: Try to change it to 15

Comment: Follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26449172/4385913) or go to project > Clear project

Comment: thanks but I've already done that and nothing changes..

Comment: Is it the root build.gradle file ?  @JoanColmenero gradle overrides this value.

Answer (score 7):

Remove this dependency from Gradle file and add from

> Project(right click) -> Project Structure ->click on your
>   application-> Dependencies -> Add button(right side) ->library
>   dependency -> Choose V7 libary.

[image]

Similarly add the module dependency using this way. Also before building the project make sure you do the same to the module project

Comment: When I add the appcompat-v7-21.0.3 it says that the library has broken paths and doesn't let me add the module dependency.

Comment: can u post excat log?

Comment: This just added the dependency I just removed back to app/build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Run `gradle clean build` command