# Android Studio : No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-actionmode

I added Google Maps Activity to my app
but I keep getting this error

No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.

I found this link and tried to apply the same solution but it did not work and I still get the same error

[appcompat-v7:21.0.0': No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro)

Anyone can help?

Comment: Have you added v7 library to your project?

Comment: where is this library?, i cant find it anywhere in the SDK manager.

Comment: you can get it here and use this library in your project. your sdk -> extras -> android -> v7

Comment: I have created a fresh app with Google Maps, it works fine. The problem is when I add google map  activity to my current app, then I get this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this

The AppCompat library was already installed
but the App was compiling under Android 19 which cases this issue

to resolve this I compiled under Android 21