# Appcompat library error : No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am developing an application for a 4.0.3 Android device(API level 15). I am using The Appcompat support library.
It seems this library only works with projects targeted to version 21.
My application runs perfectly on this version, but when I turn it to API 15, I got plenty of "no resource found that matches the given name..." errors.

```
[2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:20: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:25: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentEnd'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:33: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:42: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toEndOf'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:41: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:47: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:52: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginEnd'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:51: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:57: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:56: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:61: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:65: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:69: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:70: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:338: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:345: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:352: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:359: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:53: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:41 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:20: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:25: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentEnd'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:33: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:42: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toEndOf'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:41: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:47: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:52: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginEnd'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:51: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:57: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:56: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:61: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:65: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:69: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:70: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:338: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:345: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:352: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:359: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] 
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication] C:\Users\sb\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:53: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2015-03-23 11:59:43 - MasterApplication]
```

Comment: "It seems this library only works with projects targeted to version 21" -- no, it only works with projects that compile against the API Level 21 (or higher) version of the Android SDK. Since you appear to be using Eclipse (given references to "workspace" in your path), go to Project > Properties > Android and set your "build target" to be API Level 21 or higher.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The version of SDK you're compiling your code with should be >= the version of support libraries.

For example, if you specify this dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

Then you must also use `compileSdkVersion 21` (or later).

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro).