# Getting error at compile time in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

Hi i am trying to use eclipse for android development and i am getting this error

```
<mypath>Android\sdk1\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:144: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
```

I have already installed the required thing as in the image

[image]

What else i have to do in the setup to run the code .Please help me in this

Comment: Have you installed SDK platform for required API of your project ?

Comment: Have a look at this post; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have a SDK platfrom 21 and try to add appcompact using this tutorial. Hope this will work. :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CG_HxvV44zM

Answer (score 0):

After installation, in order to use a Support Library, you must modify your application's project's classpath dependencies within your development environment. You must perform this procedure for each Support Library you want to use.

More details here:
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library

Answer (score 0):

I see you have the extras required as Android Support Repostory, Android Support Library, Google Play Services, etc

but **you have to install the SDK platform for the API 21** too!.
And be sure to install the latest Android SDK Build-tools.

Comment: install the latest Android SDK Build-tools