# Failed to find: com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0

Tags: android, android-support-library, build.gradle

I am trying to do an application but there seems to be some error with the gradle files now. It was working fine until I upgraded the support libraries.
I was working with api 21 which worked fine, but then i upgraded to api22 and changed the gradle files accordingly.. Now this error shows up.

```
 Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0
```

This is my current gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sampleapp"
    minSdkVersion 12
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you add  `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'` to the dependency list ?

Comment: @Blackbelt : i get the same error then also.

Comment: which gradle version you are using?If outdated use the latest version and compile

Comment: @Blackbelt: ok ill check that  :)

Comment: gradle version is listed as 2.2.1 but i was using  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'  When i changed it to 2.2.1.. I got this error

Comment: Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/home/jincy/Desktop/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.pom
    file:/home/jincy/Desktop/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.jar
Required by:
    :sampleapp:unspecified

Comment: compile ('com.android.support:design:22.2.0'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
}..Try adding this

Comment: Where should I add these? inside dependencies itself?

Comment: yes..Inside the dependencies itself!!

Comment: Open your SDK Manager and upgrade build tools & support libraries to latest version.

Comment: @goonerDroid That didn't help either.

Comment: @mvai already the latest version

Comment: updated my android studio IDE and the problem got solved :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [appcompat-v7:21.0.0': No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro)

Answer (score 1):

If this might help someone, after MANY trials and errors, I found that I was targeting the wrong SDK version (an older one) in the build.gradle file corresponding to "library". To change this you can do it by hand or go to the Module Settings Menu (right click on your project folder -> Open Module Settings. Then in "library" - Properties you can change the Compile Sdk and the Build Tools Versions

[image]

Comment: Obviously this worked for me after having all support libraries and build tools up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Using Android SDK Manager. Go to `Extras` and then `Android Support Repository` and update it to the latest version.

(This is essentially the comment @natario made, but it should be an answer.)