# Error in Eclipse- Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

I updated my latest library in Eclipse. Now it's showing this error in *appCompat*:

```
[2015-07-06 18:10:52 - NewDemo] E:\Workspace3\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:136: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2015-07-06 18:10:52 - NewDemo] E:\Workspace3\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:137: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2015-07-06 18:10:52 - NewDemo] E:\Workspace3\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:146: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
[2015-07-06 18:10:52 - NewDemo] E:\Workspace3\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:150: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
```

I have the following code in my *Manifest*:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: No one is going to help you unless you start using android studio

Comment: it will not work in eclipse?

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar Both Eclipse and Android Studio will throw the same exception, the IDE used is irrelevant. Posting the AndroidManifest in the question is probably a better idea...

Comment: now No solution For Solve this?

Comment: @Kumar Did you follow this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26449172/2091181There is a solution for Eclipse

Comment: maybe exist inaccuracy  your style parent in style.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete your .eclipse in users folder and restart eclipse