# Can not resolve symbol @android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle

Tags: android, android-studio

I have changed my compileSdkVersion to 22 and targetSdkVersion to 22 (from 21), then I tried to build the project and i got error in my res\values\styles where it says

```
Error:(1) Attribute "track" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "thumbTextPadding" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "switchTextAppearance" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "switchMinWidth" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "switchPadding" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "switchStyle" has already been defined
```

I tried to revert back to 21 again but I got this issue in this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro)

in my style file i do not have any attribute called 'track', and in it i fail to resolve

```
<style name="PreferenceListHeader" parent="@android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle">
```

Also why does it talk about those attributes if I do not have it in my file? or what does it mean?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem, I was using a a library 'switchbackport' and it seems it made conflict with 'appcompat-v7-22' [after I updated] with those attributes. Check [LINK](https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport/issues/42)

I updated the library which made some other conflicts but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

try like this:-

```
 @android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.TextView.ListSeparator
```

Comment: I tried and got Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.TextView.ListSeparator'.