# "No resource found" errors when building app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I'd like to migrate my Eclipse project to Android Studio. I used to build the project with minSdkVersion=8, but I want to add new functionality that requires minSdkVersion 10.

I'm running Android Studio 1.1.0. After importing the Eclipse project ("Import project" on the main AS screen), I go to the "Project Structure" window, select the "Flavors" tab, and specify API 10 (Gingerbread) for min sdk and target sdk. When I rebuild the project, I get over 100 errors in the console that look like this:

> Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :jellyWatch:compileDebugSources]
>   :jellyWatch:clean
>   :jellyWatch:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :jellyWatch:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :jellyWatch:checkDebugManifest
>   :jellyWatch:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72200Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72200Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable750Library
>   :jellyWatch:prepareDebugDependencies
>   :jellyWatch:compileDebugAidl
>   :jellyWatch:compileDebugRenderscript
>   :jellyWatch:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   :jellyWatch:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :jellyWatch:mergeDebugAssets
>   :jellyWatch:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :jellyWatch:generateDebugResources
>   :jellyWatch:mergeDebugResources
>   /Users/oreilly/Documents/workspace/JellyWatch1/jellyWatch/src/main/res/drawable/creative_commons.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   /Users/oreilly/Documents/workspace/JellyWatch1/jellyWatch/src/main/res/drawable/mapmarker.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   /Users/oreilly/Documents/workspace/JellyWatch1/jellyWatch/src/main/res/drawable/other_29.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   /Users/oreilly/Documents/workspace/JellyWatch1/jellyWatch/src/main/res/drawable/license_label.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   /Users/oreilly/Documents/workspace/JellyWatch1/jellyWatch/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   /Users/oreilly/Documents/workspace/JellyWatch1/jellyWatch/src/main/res/drawable/mapmarker_large.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>   :jellyWatch:processDebugManifest
>   :jellyWatch:processDebugResources
>   /Users/oreilly/Documents/workspace/JellyWatch1/jellyWatch/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/res/values-v11/values.xml
>   Error:(47, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>   Error:(47, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>   Error:(47, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>   Error:(47, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>   /Users/oreilly/Documents/workspace/JellyWatch1/jellyWatch/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/res/values-v14/values.xml
>   Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>   Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>   Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>   Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>   /Users/oreilly/Documents/workspace/JellyWatch1/jellyWatch/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/res/values-v17/values.xml
>   Error:(7, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
>   Error:(11, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginEnd'.
>   Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
>   Error:(7, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
>   Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
>   Error:(7, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
>   Error:(21, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
>   Error:(24, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
>   Error:(25, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
>   Error:(7, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
>   Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
>   Error:(24, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
>   Error:(35, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
>   Error:(38, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentEnd'.
>   Error:(42, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toEndOf'.
>   Error:(35, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
>   Error:(21, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
>   /Users/oreilly/Documents/workspace/JellyWatch1/jellyWatch/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/res/values-v21/values.xml
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material'.
>   Error:(79, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
>   Error:(78, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar'.
>   Error:(79, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
>   Error:(78, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark'.
>   Error:(79, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
>   Error:(78, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar'.
>   Error:(79, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
>   Error:(78, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light'.
>   Error:(79, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
>   Error:(78, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Small'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
>   Error:(285, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
>   Error:(285, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Dialog'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog'.
>   Error:(146, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
>   Error:(148, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
>   Error:(79, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
>   Error:(78, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
>   Error:(144, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
>   Error:(145, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
>   Error:(146, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
>   Error:(148, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
>   Error:(79, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
>   Error:(78, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
>   Error:(144, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
>   Error:(145, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
>   Error:(146, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
>   Error:(148, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
>   Error:(79, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
>   Error:(78, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
>   Error:(144, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
>   Error:(145, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
>   Error:(146, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
>   Error:(148, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
>   Error:(79, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
>   Error:(78, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
>   Error:(144, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
>   Error:(145, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':jellyWatch:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/oreilly/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   Blockquote

Any ideas why I am getting these errors? How to fix this?

Thanks!
Tom

Comment: Did all your drawables successfully copy over to the drawables directory for your Android Studio project? The first error you mentioned says the actionModeShareDrawable cannot be found (or it is spelled differently).  Why are you using Android Studio 1.1 instead of the current version 1.3?

Comment: Sorry about the formatting on the log. I *think* that all the drawables copied over. I'll update my Android Studio to the current version and try again.

Comment: I upgraded to Android Studio 1.3.1, but get the same errors.

Answer (score 8):

The cause - and solution - to the problem is due to incompatibility with between my specified minSdkVersion and the app-compat library, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro).

Comment: when changing minSdk and appCompat, one may run across issues with THEMES (going from 23 to 19.1, one does not have `Holo themes`, for example).  UPVOTED, had worked 4 me.

Answer (score 6):

Just change the minSdkVersion to 'XX' sync the gradle. The concept is better explained in the below link.

```
compileSdkVersion 23
minSdkVersion 10
targetSdkVersion 23
```

https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd?linkId=20147489#.o6ctvrkgj