# Android Appcompat library giving error at compile time

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have recently upgraded my Android SDK to 6.0, and imported the new v7 appcompat library in my workspace. But the appcompat lib shows error in values-v21 folder, styles_base.xml file. 
Error is as follows : **error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 
 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.**

What can be done to solve this error?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro)

Comment: You have to use API 23 to compile your project

Answer (score 0):

That means you have to upgrade your `compileSdkVersion` in the `build.gradle` file. Assuming you have imported the `v23.0.0` release of AppCompat, your build file should be something like:

```
android
    compileSdkVersion 23 
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your.id"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23 
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        ....
    }
}
```