# What version of appcompat should I use in dependencies?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-recyclerview

I'm using the latest version of appcompat. This is my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

When I rebuild the project, I got these errors:

```
 F:\AndroidStudioProjects\recycleView\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml
    Error:(6, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
    Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
    Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'...........it goes for about 50 more lines 
    F:\AndroidStudioProjects\recycleView\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
    Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
    Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

**EDIT:**
the new dependencies (`recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'`) and errors along with it:

```
F:\AndroidStudioProjects\recycleView\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml
    Error:(6, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
    Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
    Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
    Error:(13, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
    Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginEnd'.
    Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
    Error:(23, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
    Error:(26, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
 .....
    Error:(122, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
    Error:(123, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
    F:\AndroidStudioProjects\recycleView\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
    Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
    Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

These errors are comes when I use the new dependencies

Answer (score 4):

You should always use the support libraries with the same level.

For example it is a good idea to use the last version. Currently

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

If you are using the **support libraries v23**,you **have to compile your project with API23**.

In your `build.gradle` change the `compileSdkVersion` to **23**.

```
  compileSdkVersion 23
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same version as appcompat for `RecyclerView`. So,

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

would work.

Comment: Thanks for reply but now I get this error : F:\AndroidStudioProjects\recycleView\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml

Comment: @navidjons Please update your post and show more detailed error log.

Comment: @navidjons Make sure you have downloaded extras. [Prerequirements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26449172/3501958)

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
```

I am not sure if there is a v7:23+ available for recyclerview

Comment: The recyclerview-v7:23 is currenlty the last version.