# I doing google map in android studio , but when compile . The logcat show me this error

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-styles

```
D:\Android\SCBG\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.1\res\values-ldltr-v21\values-ldltr-v21.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
```

Total is 121 error show.Its keep repeat error. Other error is almost the same as this two.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/src/googleplex-android/mnc-supportlib-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-ldltr-v21/styles_base.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined" parent="android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined"/>
</resources>
```

when i click on error , it lead me to this file. I have no idea what error in this file.( ldltr-v21/styles_base.xml  )

This is my build.gradle file.can someone tell me what to replace or type?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: it has nothing to do with google map, its with your styling ..check your styles

Comment: It's because of using different version of support library.

Comment: @PunitSharma  what  is styling. How to change it. Sorry , i am the beginner of android studio. Can help me please?

Comment: Paste your build.gradle dependency part

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro  this might help you

Comment: @Mann oh great . I will try it now.Thanks.

Comment: @Mann i still cannot resolve the problem . i follow download all requeirement. But in build.gradle file. i dont know what to replace.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar can you help  me to see the build.gradle file. And what to be replace or edit.

Comment: @huhush paste the `compile` section of your build.gradle.