# Exception in create first Android application

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new in android programming. I use Eclipse with version : Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)

I've created my first Android Application Project with below specifications:

Minimum Required SDK : API 8: Android 2.2 (Froyo)

Target SDK: API 20: Android 4.4 (KitKat Wear)

compile with : Google APIs (Google Inc.) (API 17)

but after the project has created, I saw many exceptions in console. I've searched a lot for the exception on internet but non of them worked.

> error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
>
> error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.

the exception in console is :

```
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:71: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:80: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:94: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
>
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v23\styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
>
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:42: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:62: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v23\styles_base_text.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:50: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:52: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:54: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:156: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:160: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:158: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:159: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:157: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:154: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:155: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:89: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:93: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:91: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:92: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:90: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:87: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:88: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:134: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:138: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:136: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:137: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:135: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:132: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:133: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:142: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:146: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:71: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:80: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v23\styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:195: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:199: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:110: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-ldltr-v21\styles_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v23\styles_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:107: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:114: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:104: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:119: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:131: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:136: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:122: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:125: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:139: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:143: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:147: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:151: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:157: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:161: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:165: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:90: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:94: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
> 
> D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:98: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
```

Regards

Habib

Answer (score 0):

compile with api level must be >= target api level

Minimum Required SDK : API 8: Android 2.2 (Froyo)

Target SDK: API 20: Android 4.4 (KitKat Wear) **Must be at least the same level as complie with API level**

compile with : Google APIs (Google Inc.) (API 17)  **This cannot be less than target SDK API level**

Comment: Minimum Required SDK : API 8: Android 2.2 (Froyo)
Target SDK: API 20: Android 4.4 (KitKat Wear)
compile with : Google APIs (Google Inc.) **(API 20)** must be greater or equal to target SDK level

Comment: I set target SDK to API 21 and compile with to API 22, but again Exception raised

Comment: try setting compile and target to the same level.... I can't think of any reason to have them different

Comment: what level did you set them to?

Comment: Are your libraries up to date? And are you using the latest version of the support libraries? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro

Comment: I tested with both API 21 and API 22

Comment: Are you rebuilding everytime? Is it important you use eclipse? Can you not migrate to Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

You must set up Target SDK to API 21

Comment: Try export your project into android studio. Maybe there many your questions will disappear.