# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

Tags: android, android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/sherily/android sdk/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/android-5.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

[build file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpQka.jpg)

Comment: We need the full error message.

Comment: Read: "How to ask" first please.

Comment: `Open your SDK manager and make sure you have the latest version of the support library and repository. `

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java finished with non-zero exit value 2 - Android Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help, give it a try:

```
Build -> Clean Project
```

then:

```
Build -> Rebuild Project
```