# Migrating to API 23

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

My android application currently with API 22:

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
}
dependencies {
.......
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
.......
```

}

I would like to make a migration to API 23:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
}
dependencies {
    .......
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    .......
}
```

So basically i need to keep my old version of **targetSdkVersion 22** for the reason to test some difference in permissions, but when i'm doing this it gives me error of compilation

```
....\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

**Question** : Is it possible to keep targetSdkVersion 22?

Comment: when changing sdk versions it is highly recommendable to make a clean build. Have you tried that?

Comment: First - Sync gradle, then clean build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is somewhere else because I made my gradle file look the same as your and I had no problems. Have you seen this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26449172/5433709 ?

Comment: yes that was my error - in one of libraries  compileSdkVersion was 22.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to keep targetSdkVersion 22. Android allows managing runtime permission systems via adb tool [official doc](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/best-practices.html).

Related part from the doc[image]

Comment: same I can do just in settings of my Phone... so it's just a shortcut

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for brainstorm - it works finally(code 18). Detailed check of all details gives a correct build.

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}

.... compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
```

The reason of using targetSdkVersion 22 is to see the difference between `PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission` and `context.checkSelfPermission`