# Error in AppCompat_v7 Library - Eclipse

Tags: android

I'm a new Android Programmer. I imported the AppCompat_v7 library into my project. I had an error in `appcompat_v7>res>values-v21>styles.xml`.

The error is:

> Error retrieving parent for item.No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'

[image: Error in Appcompat_v7>res>value-v21>styles.xml]

Comment: a list of solutions are here.. try it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro

Comment: Eclipse ADT has been deprecated for a year now