# style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info) not found

Tags: android

I got this error in sdk version 27. My gradle setting is

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.abc.def'
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

This [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241620/errorresource-style-textappearance-compat-notification-info-aka-packageid-te) doesn't help. I don't see anywhere use this code

```
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification"
```

just have code like this

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
```

Any idea on How to fix it? Much appreciated!

Comment: Any solutions yet?

Comment: Not yet, I use another computer with lower version of AS and Gradle. Looks like upgrading caused the issue.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I encountered this issue after I restarted my computer and there was no change made to the gradle or manifest before restarting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output: error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info (aka package\_name:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info) not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323729/output-error-resource-style-textappearance-compat-notification-info-aka-packa)

Answer (score 1):

> I think you should try adding style as below in your **styles.xml** file.

```
<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorWhichYouWant</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the correct solution and am unable to find what caused the issue but mine was solved(stopped occurring) after I migrated to androidx. [Migration guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: my problem started when i integrated android x

Comment: I don't think the issue here is about androidx or the old android libraries, since I was able to run the project in other work stations with either one. Also I am not able to find the actual issue which caused such error